How to return a value from kotlin extension
Keeping in view below code how can I add return value from alert dialog textview of spinner or any other action button. I have tried different ways but unable to get value of textview from alert dialogue
// Kotlin extension
fun Context.alert(
    @StyleRes style: Int = 0,
    dialogBuilder: MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.() -> Unit
) {
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this, style)
        .apply {
            setCancelable(false)
            dialogBuilder()
            create()
            show()
        }
}

fun MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.negativeButton(
    text: String = "No",
    handleClick: (dialogInterface: DialogInterface) -> Unit = { it.dismiss() }
) {
    this.setNegativeButton(text) { dialogInterface, _ -> handleClick(dialogInterface) }
}

fun MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.positiveButton(
    text: String = "Yes",
    handleClick: (dialogInterface: DialogInterface) -> Unit = { it.dismiss() }
) {
    this.setPositiveButton(text) { dialogInterface, _ -> handleClick(dialogInterface) }
}

fun MaterialAlertDialogBuilder.neutralButton(
    text: String = "OK",
    handleClick: (dialogInterface: DialogInterface) -> Unit = { it.dismiss() }
) {
    this.setNeutralButton(text) { dialogInterface, _ -> handleClick(dialogInterface) }
}

// Usage
alert {
    setTitle("Confirm")
    setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")
    positiveButton { textview text here }
    negativeButton { // Do something }

}
How to get value to textview here ?
positiveButton { textview text here }

